# Read a third party file - zip it - send the base64 encoded data - without saving anything

Tags: node.js, node-modules

How can one achieve this?

```js
require('request').get('http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf', function (err, response, body) {
    //zip the content in body - NO FILE SAVING
    //encode the zipped data and send as response
})
```

Please note, only zip data is required and no zip file should be saved in the system.

Answer (score 0):

request lib is not ok for this task.
you should use Streams for it. lib `request-stream` should help you (or you can use any of other libs, providing response as a `ReadableStream`)

then you should `pipe` it to `TransformStream` to zip it `zipstream` lib, for example. and so on.

Comment: could you please share an example snippet